# ODBC: ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Unable to connect to data source

Tags: powerbi, odbc, gateway, firebird2.5

I have one machine where PowerBI Desktop is installed and it's used for development.

This machine has an ODBC configured to connect to Firebird DB. PowerBI Desktop is working well and I am able to connect to the DB. When I try to connect with PBI Service and update the DB I get the following error:

```
Falha ao atualizar as credenciais da fonte de dados: ODBC: ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Unable to connect to data source: library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbclient.dll' failed to loadOcultar detalhes
ID da atividade:    1ffa7f12-441a-43e4-85f1-e1199ca04014
Solicitar ID:   f5caf86d-e14a-399c-09db-3ecd1d00fda1
Código de status:   400
Hora:   Fri Nov 11 2022 14:54:14 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
Versão do serviço:  13.0.19403.8
Versão do Cliente:  2210.5.1i 0743-train
Cluster URI:    https://wabi-brazil-south-b-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
```

The computer is running a 64bits, but Firebird, Power BI and office run a 32bits. I was getting this issue when I tried to use a 64bits Power BI, but I solved id changing to 32bits.

Does someone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The Power BI Gateway only supports 64bit drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @RafaelTrindadeMariano You need to install the 64-bit Firebird ODBC driver and the 64-bit client library (using a 64-bit Firebird server installer, selecting the client install option) and use that.